# How can I convert a string type column in a class to datetime in parse.com?

Tags: python, parse-platform, datetime-format

I have a column filled with dates. I imported all of the data using the csv importer. (parse.com)

I have tried reformatting the dates to match the formatting used in parse's other datetime fields. Here's the python I used to reformat the initial dates. It runs in a folder which contains my monthly logs as csv files. The date for changing is in the fifth column (ie - `row[4]`).

```
import os
import csv
import datetime
import time
from os import listdir
mypath = os.getcwd()

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

for each in find_csv_filenames(mypath):

    with open(each,'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        next(spamreader, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in spamreader:          
            # twilio formatting "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss PDT"  / or sometimes PST
            date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[4][:-4], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            # parse formatting"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
            row[4] = date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.1%MZ")
            row[2] = ''
            print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: You didn't mention what is the issue you are facing, what is the format you want it in (format used in parse.com is not a valid way to say the format , you would need to include examples of that format).

Comment: the format is as above:     date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.1%MZ") <-- uses the strftime formatting..    The real problem is that when I update the fields in my Parse.com class, it doesn't recognize them as proper datetimes.

Comment: Why would it? `%M` is minutes , AS YOU have already seen in the EXACT SAME DATETIME FORMAT , why do you think %M would be considered SOMETHING ELSE WHEN USED after `.1` ?

Comment: What you are looking for is `%f` , which is microsecond, but still that would give 6 digits, you have to then manually remove the last three digits, no other option.

Comment: haha oops. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm still not sure it's possible to use parse's csv importer with the column type datetime..

Comment: Can Confirm - even with correct milliseconds, importer cannot recognize datetime as a type. Only Number, String, Boolean